# how to display new screen onclick event of images in grid view?

Tags: android

i have displayed the images in grid view..
but unable to connect to another screen by clicking the image..

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are using `ImageView` for showing your images. You can use `ImageView.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener l)` method, just as you would do for a button. Inside of a listener you can start new Activity as you usually do it - smth like `startActivity(new Intent(YourCurrentActivity.this, YourTargetActivity.class));`.

Also you may find [this info](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html#EventListeners) useful.

Comment: I have written the following code, but its not working..              GridView gv=(GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridview );
        gv.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
        
        gv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
        {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent,View v,int position,long id)
            {
              
                Intent myintent=new Intent(screen2activity.this,NextActivity.class);
                startActivity(myintent);
                
                
            }
            
        }
        );

Comment: @priyanka: your code looks OK. it's hard to say why it does not start a new activity. You can also check this tutorial - http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html, maybe it'll give you some idea. Also you could add logging to your code to see if the `onItemClick()` is actually called.

Answer (score 2):

HI,

You are having images in gridView n want to open it in a new activity. for that take an image adapter like this:-

```
 imagegrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.ImageGrid);
    imagegrid.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter());       
    imagegrid.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

             String imageId = (String)parent.getAdapter().getItem(position).toString();
             Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ThemanPurchase.class);
             intent.putExtra("com.ui.SampleActivity", imageId);
             startActivity(intent);                               
        }
    });
```

hope u got the point.And in the other Activity retrieve ur image like this:-

```
in = null;
    try {
        in = new java.net.URL(url).openStream();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new PatchInputStream(in));
    ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.icon);
    iv.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
    iv.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Try this it will run.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem is same as mine, try this it works quite well.

```
        GridView g = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.myGrid);
        g.setAdapter(new GridGallery(this));

        g.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

                setContentView(R.layout.gallery);
                pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.gallery_view);
                pager.setAdapter(myPagerAdapter);
                pager.setCurrentItem(position);

                isGalleryVisible = true;
            }
        });
```